# Unterschied zwischen „aller Zeit“ und „aller Zeiten“?

Tags: difference, usage

[Im Wörterbuch](http://www.dict.cc/?s=of+all+time) sind sowohl *aller Zeit* als auch *aller Zeiten* als Übersetzung von *of all time* aufgelistet. Persönlich bin ich viel vertrauter mit *aller Zeiten*. Deshalb möchte ich die Frage stellen, ob es Situationen gibt, in denen man *aller Zeit* bevorzugen sollte. Gibt es Unterschiede zwischen den beiden, oder ist *aller Zeit* einfach eine veraltete Version von *aller Zeiten*?

Comment: "Aller Zeiten" ist halt perfekter (sic)... wie in "von Ewigkeit zu Ewigkeit" im Gebet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich weiß nicht, woher dict.cc die seltsame Übersetzung *aller Zeit* für *of all time* nimmt. Mir fällt gerade kein Beispiel ein, wo das passt. Generell ist für das Sprachpaar Deutsch-Englisch dict.leo.org das mit großem Abstand verlässlichste Online-Wörterbuch. Dort wird *of all time* nur mit *aller Zeiten* übersetzt.

Die Wortfolge *aller Zeit* kommt durchaus gelegentlich (selten) vor, hat aber in der Regel eine völlig andere Bedeutung:

- vor aller Zeit – before time [= the concept in physics]
- am Ende aller Zeit – at the end of time [= the concept in physics]
- mit aller Zeit der Welt – with all the time in the world

Bei allen Beispielen handelt es sich um einen Dativ oder Genitiv von *alle Zeit* bzw. *alle Zeit der Welt*. Gemeint ist immer *Zeit* als abstraktes oder physikalisches Konzept, das keinen Plural hat. Das ist bei *of all time* in der Regel nicht gemeint. Wenn es um *Zeit* mit einem möglichen Plural geht – also Zeitpunkte oder Zeiträume –, dann benutzt das Deutsche praktisch immer *alle Zeiten* oder *jede Zeit*.

Der abstrakte Begriff *Zeit* in einer Metapher für *immer* ist im Deutschen nicht üblich. Am nächsten kommt vielleicht die feste Wendung *alle Zeit der Welt*. Ansonsten spricht man immer von *Zeiten*, d.h. *Zeiträumen*, oder vielleicht auch mal *Zeitpunkten*. Die Wortfolge *aller Zeiten* (of all times) ist dementsprechend viel häufiger als *aller Zeit*.

Früher war auch die Wendung *zu aller Zeit* (at any time) gebräuchlich. Heute wird sie aber kaum noch benutzt. Man sagt stattdessen viel eher *jederzeit*.

Comment: +1, danke fürs aufdröseln!